# Android При повороте экрана установленный язык сбивается

Tags: android

```
@Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    }
```

У меня есть 2 языка в приложении. Арабский и Английский. Кроме этого сам телефон работает на русском языке.

Когда я захожу в приложение то могу программно поменять язык приложения на арабский.

После я смотрю видео и переворачиваю экран. Вызывается onConfigurationChanged.
А перед этим Layout берется из папки English. Хотя должен браться из Arabic.

Какой именно обработчик я должен вызвать чтобы изменить configuration с English на Arabic.

Чтобы при создании окна. layout взялся из Arabic

Comment: Покажите код, который позволяет "программно поменять язык приложения на арабский".

Comment: А если тупо вызвать `newConfig.setLocale(new Locale("ar"));` - не поможет?

Comment: Все вопрос исчерпан. Проблема была в том что при повороте надо было зановго приложение менять язык.